# Why does pygame icon change color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a Minesweeper in pygame but when I set the icon it changes the color. The [icon that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG34m.png) is bluer than the [expected icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlZFD.png) and I don't understand why. Here's the code that I use:

Actual Icon [image: actual icon]

Expected Icon  [image: expected icon]

```py
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
window = pg.display.set_mode(size)

icon = pg.image.load("icon.png")
pg.display.set_icon(icon)
pg.display.set_caption("Minesweeper")
```

I tried to use `icon = pg.image.load("icon.png").convert()` and `icon = pg.image.load("icon.png").convert_alpha()` but it doesn't work.

Do you know why it does this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PNG file has some embedded information or formatting that is causing this distortion. I saved the image as a bitmap [image: bitmap icon] using paint.net and it displays without modification:

[image]

Perhaps some conversion commands could transform your image as desired, but it's probably easier to do the image manipulation outside of pygame.